# Qt Animate Tool Button

Tags: qt, animated

I tried to animate a tool button using QPropertyAnimation. However, it did nothing. Is there anything I have done wrong? Can anyone please help?

ToolBarPalettes.h:

```
class ToolBarPalettes : public QToolBar
{
   public:
      ToolBarPalettes(void);
      ~ToolBarPalettes(void);

   public slots:
      void startAnimation();

   private:
      createButtons();
      QToolButton *animatedButton;
}
```

ToolBarPalettes.cpp:

```
ToolBarPalettes::ToolBarPalettes(void)
{
   createButtons();
   connect(animatedButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startAnimation()));
}

void ToolBarPalettes::createButtons()
{
   animatedButton = new QToolButton;
   animatedButton->setText("Animate!");
   addWidget(animatedButton);
}

void ToolBarPalettes::startAnimation()
{
   QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(animatedButton, "geometry");
   animation->setDuration(3000);
   animation->setStartValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()));
   animation->setEndValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), 10, 10));
   animation->setEasingCurve::OutBounce);
   animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

Comment: If you try to call `animatedButton->setGeometry(...)` you will probably notice that nothing will happen. Try a different property like [minimumSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop).

Comment: @thuga: I did not call `animatedButton->setGeometry(...)`. I want to try clicking on the button to change its size (making it bigger or smaller) with a nice animation effect. The button should stay in its initial place without moving anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My point is that it might not work with the `geometry` property. That is why I suggested `minimumSize` property.  `maximumSize` or `size` property might also work, I'm not sure though. [Here is a list of properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#properties) you can try.

Comment: @thuga: Do you mean when I use `minimumSize` property, I have to change the following to:

`animation->setStartValue(QRect(animatedButton->x(), animatedButton->y(), animatedButton->width(), animatedButton->height()));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(animatedButton->x(), animatedButton->y(), animatedButton->minimumWidth(), animatedButton->minimumHeight()));`


What do I have to change for this statement:
`QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(animatedButton, "geometry");`

Comment: I am saying that you should use the `minimumSize`, `maximumSize` or `size` properties instead of the `geometry` property. `animation = new QPropertyAnimation(animatedButton, "minimumSize");` then set the values: `animation->setStartValue(animatedButton->minimumSize());` and `animation->setEndValue(QSize(100,100));`

Comment: @thuga: Thanks for the explanation. Using `minimumSize` works very well. I didn't know we can use this other than `geometry`. Is there any ways I can credit you for your help? :)

Comment: I formed my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `minimumSize`, `maximumSize` or `size` properties instead of the `geometry` property.

```
animation = new QPropertyAnimation(animatedButton, "minimumSize");
```

then set the values:

```
animation->setStartValue(animatedButton->minimumSize());
animation->setEndValue(QSize(100,100));
```

The `geometry` property only works for top-level windows and widget's that are not contained in a layout.